# Using SELECT in the WHERE clause - Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible, we do SELECT in the WHERE clause when we use Eloquent in Laravel?

If it is possible, could you give me an example?

Now, I use Laravel 5.2.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes off course you can use `WhereHas` function

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)